# Limit on YouTube Videos I can upload everyday

Tags: youtube-api

I am working on a YouTube channel where I have to upload thousands of short videos. To automate the boring process I decided to write a Python program that can upload all my videos and set appropriate tags, descriptions etc.

I created a Project in Developers console created API clients acquired appropriate credentials, requested and got my daily API Usage quoted extended to 500,000 units every day.
Now that I started uploading videos I am facing a different problem, i.e. the number of videos i can upload in one day. After every 100 clips i get Auth errors which say i have exceeded the daily limit of number of videos i can upload.

I want to know why is there a limit on the number of videos if i have decent API usage quota to spare.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask for help from YouTube, the owner of the API you are using.

Comment: a) that channel sounds like a nightmare, b) you probably should reach out to youtube to see if you can get your quota changed for uploads.